# Как узнать, сколько дней прошло со дня посещения сайта?

Tags: php

Посетителю сайта каждый день в определенном блоке нужно показывать новое сообщение. При посещении сайта посетителю пишется cookie со временем посещения в формате timestamp. Как на основе этого времени показывать пользователю каждый день с 00:01 новое сообщение? Например, я посетил сайт в 16:33 и увидел одно сообщение. Если я зайду завтра в 00:01, то уже должно показываться другое сообщение. Ещё через день - третье и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1400000000));
$datetime2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$Diff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $Diff->y.' Года <br/>';
echo $Diff->m.' Месяцев <br/>';
echo $Diff->d.' Дней <br/>';
echo $Diff->h.' Часов <br/>';
echo $Diff->i.' Минуты <br/>';
echo $Diff->s.' Секунд <br/>';
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/265ec41b1594f448e78d92eea11a8e7d13877618)

Comment: И для чего разница двух дат?

Comment: Ну у вас же две даты? Последнего посещения и текущая? `$Diff->d` Покажет вам разницу в днях, например.